# (C++ ) Dealing with StretchBlt() and AlphaBlend() 's image size limitations (32768)?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, stretch, cdc

As I learned from bitter experience, these two MSDN functions will refuse to display an image that is wider than 32 767 logical units.

My aim is to create a zoomable image display of very large images (as wide as 262,144 pixels but only as high as a few hundred).

```
BOOL AlphaBlend(
   int xDest,
   int yDest,
   int nDestWidth,
   int nDestHeight,
   CDC* pSrcDC,
   int xSrc,
   int ySrc,
   int nSrcWidth,
   int nSrcHeight,
   BLENDFUNCTION blend 
);
```

I get two types of problems with the above arguments:

1) nSrcWidth is simply too large and the image doesn't get displayed. Chopping the image into parts won't work because then xDest will be too large.

2) When zooming I magnify the image and nDestWidth becomes too large; as a result zooming more than a given ratio makes the image disappear.

Is there some function/class/method I could use to avoid these limitations or am I forced to work around them?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Even if picture is as wide as 262,144 pixels there is no need to load or draw parts larger than typical display. You may want to split it into smaller blocks (1024x1024 for example), load and draw them on demand. Efficient zooming can be achieved with prerendered image parts at smaller resolution.

Comment: Thanks! What functions will let me load an image partially?